# How does one normalize observations in online reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, model-free-methods

I was wondering how would one normalize observations to a policy without knowing the upper and lower limits of the environment values. A trivial technique would be normalize each observation by its maximum value before inputting it into a policy. However, I feel that doing so, could change the distribution of the data. For instance, let's say we have 2 inputs that we normalize on the fly - [5, 15, 20] and [10, 20, 30] to [0.25, .75, 1] and [0.33, .66 and 1]. Now let's say the true maximum value of the environment is 100. Then the true normalized values should have been [0.05, .15, .20] and [0.1, .20, 0.3]. Wouldn't this adversely affect learning?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261940/how-do-i-normalize-data-in-online-learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can compute a *running mean*, $\mu_t$, and std, $\sigma_t$, of your online data $x_t$, and then standardize at each timestep, $t$:
$$\begin{align}
\mu_t &\leftarrow \mu_{t+1} + \frac{(x_t - \mu_{t-1})}{n}\\
n &\leftarrow n + 1 \\
\sigma_t &\leftarrow \sigma_{t-1} + (x_t - \mu_t) * (x_t - \mu_{t-1})
\end{align}$$

Initially you would have: $\mu_0=0$, $\sigma_0=1$, and $n=1$.

For reference see: [1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/811/determining-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-real-time) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance).